# Cannot find driving mode on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, driving-mode

After upgrading to the new Android 4.1.2, I can't seem to find the 'driving mode' tab.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried in `Settings > Language and input > Text to speech output > Driving mode`?

Answer (score 0):

It's at the top, when you pull down to select WiFi,  GPS, screen rotation, etc.

Comment: In the most recent version of Android for Samsung (4.1.2) the driving mode is no longer in the top drawer. You can find it as described by @geffchang.